# Difference between mpi and mpich2 folder?

Tags: linux, mpi

so configuring the MPI flags I have realized that in the `/usr/include` directory there are two folders with the same files. So two related questions:

- Is this normal for an MPICH installation?
- What's the difference between them?

All the best and thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can depend on your installation, but this is a common way for providing several parallel MPI installation.

I have both MPICH2 and OpenMPI installed, and this folders in `/usr/include`:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     21 Apr  1 17:03 mpi -> /etc/alternatives/mpi/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Apr  1 17:03 mpich/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     22 Nov 30 01:21 openmpi -> ../lib/openmpi/include/
```

And `mpi` folder is a folder which should be used as `#include` to make use of `alternatives` mechanism (I recommend starting from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/233190/what-exactly-does-update-alternatives-do) and [this](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/91/Using_the_Debian_alternatives_system), it's available on other than Debian based distros).

If you run `update-alternatives --config mpi` you can change the default MPI distribution.

Example, `/etc/alternatives/mpi` before and after `update-alternatives`:

```
# before, pointing to MPICH2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Apr  1 17:14 /etc/alternatives/mpi -> /usr/include/mpich/
# and after, pointing to OpenMPI
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Apr  1 17:07 /etc/alternatives/mpi -> /usr/lib/openmpi/include/
```

---

Summarizing:

1. Use `/usr/include/mpi/` to make your code as much portable as possible.
2. Use `update-alternatives` to change the desired MPI distro.
3. This is a mechanism of `alternatives` to provide easy way of multiple version (and distributions) of software.

Comment: Related (and with no answer yet)... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66535019/switch-from-mpich-to-openmpi