# Switch from MPICH to OpenMPI

Tags: mpi, openmpi, ubuntu-20.04, mpich

I have both mpich and openmpi in my Ubuntu 20.04.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep mpi | grep lib
...
ii  libmpich-dev:amd64                            3.3.2-2build1                         amd64        Development files for MPICH
ii  libmpich12:amd64                              3.3.2-2build1                         amd64        Shared libraries for MPICH
...
ii  libopenmpi-dev:amd64                          4.0.3-0ubuntu1                        amd64        high performance message passing library -- header files
ii  libopenmpi3:amd64                             4.0.3-0ubuntu1                        amd64        high performance message passing library -- shared library
...
ii  openmpi-bin                                   4.0.3-0ubuntu1                        amd64        high performance message passing library -- binaries
ii  openmpi-common                                4.0.3-0ubuntu1                        all          high performance message passing library -- common files
..
$ dpkg -l | grep mpich
...
ii  mpich                                         3.3.2-2build1                         amd64        Implementation of the MPI Message Passing Interface standard
```

The default (probably because it was installed later) appears to be mpich.

**How would I change to openmpi?**

I want to make sure that everything that needs to be changed actually is.
So far, I am thinking about headers, executable, libraries.
I do not know which are all directories, links, etc., that have to change.

For instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016418/cmake-selecting-mpich-over-openmpi#comment91012586_52016418) it is suggested `cmake -DMPI_CC_COMPILER=/.../mpicc`.
And it was mentioned in comments that it worked. But:

1. I am not sure it actually fixes all headers, etc.
2. I need a method that:

   2.1. Works for all users in the system

   2.2. Does not require those macros

   2.3. Works also for other compilation methods other than `cmake`

As for 2.3, I tried now to configure petsc

```
$ ./configure --with-cc=mpicc --with-fc=mpif90 -with-cxx=mpicxx --with- make-np=10 --with-shared-libraries --download-f2cblaslapack --download-mumps --download-scalapack --with-debugging=0 COPTFLAGS="-O -O3 -march=native -mtune=native" FOPTF LAGS="-O -O3 -march=native -mtune=native" CXXOPTFLAGS="-O -O3 -march=native -mtune=native"
```

and I got

```
Your libraries are from MPICH but it appears your mpiexec is from OpenMPI
```

---

**Can this be fixed with `update-alternatives`?**

I found this, which makes me think it can, but in my system it is not correctly configured:

```
$ type mpiexec
mpiexec is hashed (/usr/bin/mpiexec)
$ ll /usr/bin/mpiexec
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jan 21 11:11 /usr/bin/mpiexec -> /etc/alternatives/mpiexec
$ ll /etc/alternatives/mpiexec
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jan 21 11:11 /etc/alternatives/mpiexec -> /usr/bin/mpiexec.openmpi
$ ll /usr/bin/mpiexec.openmpi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr 15  2020 /usr/bin/mpiexec.openmpi -> orterun

$ type mpirun
mpirun is /usr/bin/mpirun
$ ll /usr/bin/mpirun
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jan 21 11:11 /usr/bin/mpirun -> /etc/alternatives/mpirun
$ ll /etc/alternatives/mpirun
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 23 Jan 21 11:11 /etc/alternatives/mpirun -> /usr/bin/mpirun.openmpi
$ ll /usr/bin/mpirun.openmpi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr 15  2020 /usr/bin/mpirun.openmpi -> orterun

$ type mpicc
mpicc is hashed (/usr/bin/mpicc)
$ ll /usr/bin/mpicc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Feb 25 18:54 /usr/bin/mpicc -> /etc/alternatives/mpi
$ ll /etc/alternatives/mpi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Feb 25 18:54 /etc/alternatives/mpi -> /usr/bin/mpicc.mpich
```

---

**Related**

1. [Replace MPICH Installation by OpenMPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568197/replace-mpich-installation-by-openmpi)
2. [CMake : Selecting mpich over openmpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016418/cmake-selecting-mpich-over-openmpi)
3. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413099/flip-between-openmpi-and-mpich-as-default-using-linux-terminal
4. [Difference between mpi and mpich2 folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29369208/difference-between-mpi-and-mpich2-folder)
5. [CMake : Selecting mpich over openmpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52016418/cmake-selecting-mpich-over-openmpi)
6. [Switch from MPICH to OpenMPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66535019/switch-from-mpich-to-openmpi)
7. This? https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=896189
8. This? https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=912437
9. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81992/better-way-to-add-alternative-using-update-alternatives
10. https://askubuntu.com/questions/964600/how-to-add-slave-to-existing-update-alternatives-link-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems all [alternatives](https://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives), except for one (*link group* `mpi`), were already set for openmpi

```
$ update-alternatives --get-selections | grep mpi
h5pcc                          auto     /usr/bin/h5pcc.openmpi
mpi                            auto     /usr/bin/mpicc.mpich
mpi-x86_64-linux-gnu           auto     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include
mpirun                         auto     /usr/bin/mpirun.openmpi
```

To set link group `mpi` properly (and avoiding error-prone individual link operations)

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall openmpi-bin
```

(the package owning `mpicc.openmpi`).
This apparently fixed everything.
So far it is working fine.

---

**"Historical" note**:
I had found that (strangely) `mpicc.openmpi` was not in `update-alternatives`, as opposed to the other 3 link groups

```
$ update-alternatives --list mpirun
/usr/bin/mpirun.mpich
/usr/bin/mpirun.openmpi
$ update-alternatives --list h5pcc
/usr/bin/h5pcc.mpich
/usr/bin/h5pcc.openmpi
$ update-alternatives --list mpi-x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/mpich
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include
$ update-alternatives --list mpi
/usr/bin/mpicc.mpich
```

even if it was installed in my system

```
$ ll /usr/bin/mpicc*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  21 Feb 25 18:54 /usr/bin/mpicc -> /etc/alternatives/mpi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 11K Mar 22  2020 /usr/bin/mpicc.mpich
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  12 Apr 15  2020 /usr/bin/mpicc.openmpi -> opal_wrapper
```

Why would it not be in the first place? I still don't know.

I decided to go with the `reinstall`, since handling the link group manually might have been a mess

```
$ update-alternatives --query mpi
Name: mpi
Link: /usr/bin/mpicc
Slaves:
 mpiCC /usr/bin/mpiCC
 mpiCC.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mpiCC.1.gz
 mpic++ /usr/bin/mpic++
 mpic++.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mpic++.1.gz
 mpicc.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mpicc.1.gz
 mpicxx /usr/bin/mpicxx
 mpicxx.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mpicxx.1.gz
 mpif77 /usr/bin/mpif77
 mpif77.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mpif77.1.gz
 mpif90 /usr/bin/mpif90
 mpif90.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mpif90.1.gz
 mpifort /usr/bin/mpifort
 mpifort.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mpifort.1.gz
Status: auto
Best: /usr/bin/mpicc.mpich
Value: /usr/bin/mpicc.mpich

Alternative: /usr/bin/mpicc.mpich
Priority: 40
Slaves:
 mpiCC /usr/bin/mpicxx.mpich
 mpiCC.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mpicxx.mpich.1.gz
 mpic++ /usr/bin/mpicxx.mpich
 mpic++.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mpicxx.mpich.1.gz
 mpicc.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mpicc.mpich.1.gz
 mpicxx /usr/bin/mpicxx.mpich
 mpicxx.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mpicxx.mpich.1.gz
 mpif77 /usr/bin/mpifort.mpich
 mpif77.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mpif77.mpich.1.gz
 mpif90 /usr/bin/mpifort.mpich
 mpif90.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mpif90.mpich.1.gz
 mpifort /usr/bin/mpifort.mpich
 mpifort.1.gz /usr/share/man/man1/mpifort.mpich.1.gz
```